# Removal of parenthesis around years from the citations in text

Tags: citing, natbib

I have an Elsevier article to submit and I've been given a Latex file. It has the following code

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}                 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

The manuscript is here.


\bibliography{referenceFile} 
\bibliographystyle{apa}\biboptions{authoryear}


\end{document}
```

The references in the manuscript appear as (AuthorName (Year)) as in the picture below but I want to change it to (AuthorName, Year).

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I change it? I added all packages I'm using, in case any package clashes somehow with references.

I can't see any reference packages like `biblatex` or `natbib`. What am I missing? Or do I change the structure of any other file than the .tex?

Comment: Are you using (say) `(\cite{sharma2018})`? Try `\citep{sharma2018}` for citations in parentheses.

Comment: \citep{sharma2018} did work!